# Get Table Index

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

In Google Docs you can get an array of table using the following code

```
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
var body = doc.getBody();
var tables = body.getTables();
```

However if I get an element of a table using the cursor I would like to know which table in the array the element belongs to.  There are methods to get the row and cell of the element in a table but no method that I can find that will give me the index of the parent table in the table array.  Any suggestions?

```
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
var cursor = doc.getCursor();
```

Answer (score 1):

- You can iterate through the parents of the cursor until you get to the table:

```js
  var element = cursor.getElement();
  while (element.getType() != "TABLE" && element.getType() != "BODY_SECTION"){
  element = element.getParent();
  } 
  Logger.log(element);
```

- Once you get to the table, you can obtain the child index of the table in its parent (usually `BODY_SECTION`):

```js
  if(element.getType() == "TABLE"){
    var index = element.getParent().getChildIndex(element);
    Logger.log(index);
  }
```

Important:

- The index will be the position of the parent table iwthin the body section, but beare that your body section might conatin also other elements than tables, so you need to know the correspondance betwwen tables and body indices.

You can implement it e.g. with

```
  var tables = body.getTables().forEach(function(table){
    Logger.log(body.getChildIndex(table))
});
```

Full sample:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var tableIndices = [];
  var tables = body.getTables().forEach(function(table){tableIndices.push(body.getChildIndex(table))});
  var cursor = doc.getCursor();
  var element = cursor.getElement();
  while (element.getType() != "TABLE" && element.getType() != "BODY_SECTION"){
    element = element.getParent();
  } 
  Logger.log(element);
  if(element.getType() == "TABLE"){
    var index = element.getParent().getChildIndex(element);
    var tableNumber = tableIndices.indexOf(index)+1;
    Logger.log("The cursor is inside table " + tableNumber);
  }
}
```

Comment: As written your code does not give the correct value if there is a mixture of tables, text and other items.  For example, in my test case, my cursor is in the second table but the index returned is 6.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense. This is what my "Important" section is about: You need to separately determine the indices of different elements in your body. For example, if the indices of your tables are 2, 4 and 6 and the element containing the cursor has the index 6 -you know that it is the third table. You can implement it programmatically for example by pushing the indices of your tables into an array and then compare the index of the cursor containing element against the position of the corresponding index of the table in the array. I hope I explain myself in an understandable way.

Comment: Thanks I have thought about doing what you suggest.  Just hoping there was an easier solution.

Comment: It's not as complicated as you might think - I added a full sample to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ziganotschka I figured out a solution.

```
function test() {
  try {
    var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
    var body = doc.getBody();
    var cursor = doc.getCursor();
    var element = cursor.getElement();
    while( element.getType() !== DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE ) {
      element = element.getParent();
      if( element === null ) return;  // did not pick a table
    }
    var bIndex = element.getParent().getChildIndex(element);
    Logger.log("bIndex= "+bIndex);
    var i = 0;
    var tIndex = -1;
    var child = null;
    while( i <= bIndex ) {
      child = body.getChild(i);
      Logger.log("i= "+i+" child= "+child)
      if( child.getType() === DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE ) tIndex++;
      i++;
    }
    DocumentApp.getUi().alert("tIndex= "+tIndex);
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log("Error in test: "+err);
  }
};
```